# Angular2 Return an already resolved promise

Tags: typescript, angular

I'd like to create and return an already resolved (fake if you prefer) Promise in angular2. In angularjs you would do something like : `return $q.defer().promise`

I was thinking about doing : `return new Observable<any>.toPromise()`
However I am not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Promise.resolve('someValue');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Thanks Sir, exactly what I needed